# Is there a way to add another cell to my search function?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Here is my current formula

```
var Search_Col_IDX = 0;
function Search() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var formS = ss.getSheetByName("Form"); //Form Sheet

  var str = formS.getRange ("h2").getValue();
  var values=ss.getSheetByName("Data").getDataRange().getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    var row = values[i];
    if (row[Search_Col_IDX]== str) {

  formS.getRange("h7").setValue(row[2]);
  formS.getRange("h9").setValue(row[3]);
  formS.getRange("h11").setValue(row[4]);
  formS.getRange("h5").setValue(row[0]);
  formS.getRange("j5").setValue(row[1]);
  formS.getRange("j7").setValue(row[5]);
  formS.getRange("j9").setValue(row[6]);
  formS.getRange("j11").setValue(row[7]);
} }}
```

This formula is currently getting the data based on the week that is found in "h2". But I would like to add another condition to it so it pulls the exercise found in that week, so I can cycle through exercise in the same week. The data is being pulled in from my "Data" sheet and the week is found in column 0, and the exercises are found in column 1. What can I add to this function to add the search criteria?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var Search_Col_IDX = 0;
function Search() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Form");
  const rgl = sh.getRangeList(["H5", "J5", "H7", "H9", "H11", "J7", "J9", "J11"]);
  const dsh = ss.getSheetByName("Data");
  const vs = dsh.getDataRange().getValues();
  const srg = dsh.getRange(1, Search_ColIDX + 1, dsh.getLastRow(), 1);
  const str = sh.getRange("h2").getValue();
  srg.createTextFinder(str).findAll().forEach((rg, i) => {
    let row = vs[rg.getRow() - 1];
    rgl.getRanges().forEach((r, j) => {
      r.setValue(r[j]);
    })
  });
}
```